# Looking for a simple ASP.Net web site sample

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ADO.Net + ASP.Net + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise + IIS 7.0. I want to save my time to write an simple ASP.Net web site. And want to see if I can find an available one here. :-)

What I need is very simple, (1) basic UI (2) could edit/update/delete data from database (any kinds of data is fine, like order information, customer information, people information, etc.). I need a simple sample with source codes and do not need a heavy/complex one, my purpose is just to test my web site deployment script using some web sites not developed by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some projects you could use:

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Here you have some MVC apps:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/

Comment: All of them looks great! For such starter kit project, I have downloaded and installed the vsi files, but how to use them?

Comment: the project is propably placed in C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Web Developer\CSharp. You have to open Visual Studio and select File -> Open -> Web site...

Comment: Cool, thanks question answered!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the starter kits on www.asp.net:

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Comment: For such starter kit project, I have downloaded and installed the vsi files, but how to use them?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Blogengine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)

if you are looking for .net 3.5 then [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) it is. It will also introduce you to asp.net mvc

Comment: For such starter kit project, I have downloaded and installed the vsi files, but how to use them?